# Hide parent div if child div is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible at all to hide a parent div if there is a child div missing?

In the example below I would like to hide the parent div of "#live-sessions" if some of the divs are missing such as .views-content and .views-row.

This is what it looks like when the divs are there:

```
<div id="live-sessions">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h3 class="session-title">Sessions Live Now</h3>

                    <div class="col-sm-9">

                       <div class-"view-display-id-live_sessions">

                            <div class="views-content">

                               <div class="views-row">
                               </div>

                               <div class="views-row">
                               </div>

                           </div>

                       </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

This is what it looks like when the divs are missing:

```
<div id="live-sessions">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h3 class="session-title">Sessions Live Now</h3>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">

                           <div class-"view-display-id-live_sessions">


                           </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

I tried using the :empty selector with the parent method, but my child div contains some blank lines so it doesn't think it's empty. Also I would like to hide the parent of the parent of the empty div.

```
$(".view-display-id-live_sessions:empty").parent().hide();
```

Comment: Are we hiding both the row and the parent of #live-sessions?

Comment: I'd like everything to be hidden including the #live-sessions DIV. So basically that entire block with everything inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your html:

```
class-"view-display-id-live_sessions"
```

should be

```
class="view-display-id-live_sessions"
```

you can try the following jQuery code:

```
if ($(".view-display-id-live_sessions").html().trim() == '') {
    $(".view-display-id-live_sessions").parent().parent().hide();
}
```

[jqVersion demo](http://www.jqversion.com/#!/qWEJBrC)

Comment: Thanks Matei! I added one more .parent() to target the DIV I wanted and that works.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `has()` in a negative if test - http://api.jquery.com/has/

```
if(!$('#parent').has('.child')){
  $('#parent').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a one-line-query for this. Following code would do the trick:

```
$('#live-sessions .row').each(function(idx, row) {
    if ($(row).find('.views-content').length == 0) {
        $(row).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using jQuery, you could instead do:

```
if ( ! $(".view-display-id-live_sessions").children().length ) { /* your logic */ }
```

Note that there's a syntax error in your code:

```
 <div class-"view-display-id-live_sessions">
```

Should be

```
 <div class="view-display-id-live_sessions">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim the blank spaces, correct a typo and test for the text within the div -

```
class="view-display-id-live_sessions" // note the equals sign after class
```

The code to do the hiding (EDIT re-read problem again):

```
var liveSessionsText = $.trim( $('.view-display-id-live_sessions').text() );
if(0 == liveSessionsText.length) {
    $('.view-display-id-live_sessions').closest('.row').hide();
}
```

The div with class="row" is the parent of the parent of view-display-id-live_sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand your question:

First you need to check the number of .views-row divs. If the length is zero hide the parent div.

Ex:

```
if ($('.views-row').length < 1)
   $('#live-sessions').hide();
```

Good Luck.